# Writing properly formatted JSON to S3 to load in Athena/Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-athena, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I have a trigger that is executing a lambda function for each transaction received on Kinesis. The producer is sending multiple transactions via the PutRecordsRequest() method. Lambda function is as follows;

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var firehose = new AWS.Firehose();
var fhStreamName = "transactions";

function writeToS3(jsonString,firehoseStreamName){

    console.log("Writing to S3 : " + jsonString)

    // Prepare storage to postings firehose stream...
    var params = { 
        DeliveryStreamName: firehoseStreamName, 
        Record: { 
            Data:  jsonString
        }
    };

    // Store data!
    firehose.putRecord(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) { 

            // This needs to be fired to Kinesis in the future...
            console.log(err, err.stack); 
        }
        else{  
            console.log(data);            
        }
    });
}

function processEvent(event) {

    // Convert data object because this is all that we need
    var buf = new Buffer(event, "base64"); 

    // Convert to actual string which is readable
    var jsonString = buf.toString("utf8");

    return jsonString;
}   

exports.handler = function(event, context) {  

    var result = "";  

    // Loop events and register to firehose...  
    for(var i=0; i<event.Records.length; i++){
        result = result + processEvent(event.Records[i].kinesis.data,fhStreamName); 
    }   

    writeToS3(result,fhStreamName); 

    context.done();
};
```

However when writing transactions, on S3 they aren't written as a JSON array. The following is an example:

```
{
  "userName" : "val1",
  "betID" : "val2",
  "anotherID" : val3
}{
  "userName" : "val4",
  "anotherID" : "val5",
  "productID" : val6, 
}
```

Can this data in this format be loaded directly to Athena or Redshift, or does it have to be in a valid array? I can see here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-usage_notes-copy-from-json.html that it should still be able to load into Redshift.

Here are the properties used when creating the table in Athena...

```
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  'serialization.format' = '1'
) LOCATION 's3://asgaard-data/data/'
```

How can I load this data to be able to query it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For others that might have same problem, this is the code that fixed my issue and data is now properly formatted for Athena, Redshift etc. It's in node. Data goes to Kinesis from my producers, each transaction has a trigger, and transactions are processed one by one and sent to firehose which in the end writes to S3.

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk'); 
var firehose = new AWS.Firehose();
var fhStreamName = "transactions";

function processEvent(event,firehoseStreamName) {

    // Convert data object because this is all that we need
    var buf = new Buffer(event, "base64"); 

    // Convert to actual string which is readable
    var jsonString = buf.toString("utf8"); 

    // Prepare storage to postings firehose stream...
    var params = { 
        DeliveryStreamName: firehoseStreamName, 
        Record: { 
            Data:  jsonString.replace(/\n|\r/g, "")  + "\n"
        }
    };

    console.log("Writing : " + params.Record.Data)

    // Store data!
    firehose.putRecord(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) { 

            // This needs to be fired to Kinesis in the future...
            console.log(err, err.stack); 
        }
        else{  
            //console.log(data);            
        }
    });
}   

exports.handler = function(event, context) {   

     // Loop events and register to firehose...  
     for(var i=0; i<event.Records.length; i++){
         processEvent(event.Records[i].kinesis.data,fhStreamName); 
     }  

    context.done();
};
```

Comment: Is this a transformation lambda associated with Kinesis Firehose in your case?

Comment: It's a kinesis trigger. You write a Lambda, then attach the trigger to it where the kinesis stream is specified. The triggers apply the transformation early on from the kinesis stream to the firehose, in this example.

Answer (score 5):

For Athena, the JSON records need to be one object per line:

```
{ "userName" : "val1", "betID" : "val2", "anotherID" : val3 }
{ "userName" : "val4", "anotherID" : "val5", "productID" : val6 }
```

This can seem counter-intuitive because the resulting file is not a well-formed JSON object itself, but the newline-delimited text is good for Athena, Hive, and similar processing tools.  I believe the same structure will work for Redshift, but Redshift has more options.

Comment: And the formatting (JSON in 1 liner) is taken care of in the lambda expression feeding firehose?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the callback - also it's best to batch records and use the callback just once. Here is the amended function:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk'); 
var firehose = new AWS.Firehose({region: 'us-east-1'});
var fhStreamName = "transaction";

function add_newline(data) {
    var buf = new Buffer(data, "base64"); 
    var jsonString = buf.toString("utf8"); 
    return jsonString.replace(/\n|\r/g, "")  + "\n"
}

exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {   

    if (event.Records) { 
         console.log(JSON.stringify(event.Records))

        // Loop events and register to firehose...  
        const records_arr =  
            event.Records.map(record => {
                return {Data: add_newline(record.kinesis.data)}
            });

        const params =
          {
            DeliveryStreamName: fhStreamName, /* required */
            Records: records_arr
          };

        firehose.putRecordBatch(params, function(err, data) {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
            callback(err);
          }
          else {
            console.log("Wrote data to firehose ->");
            console.log(data);    
            callback(null);
          }
        });         
    }
};
```